# Undefined Symbol for architecture i386 armv7, armv7s MedioEvent k-invite sdk

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x

I have tried removig the following error by following many solutions here and on other forums.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
      "_kABPersonPhoneProperty", referenced from:
          +[InviteHelpers findPhoneNumbersForContact:] in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
      "_ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople", referenced from:
          _CopyValuesFromLinkedContact in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
      "_ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex", referenced from:
          _CopyValuesFromLinkedContact in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
      "_ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel", referenced from:
          _CopyValuesFromLinkedContact in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
      "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
          +[InviteHelpers findEmailsForContact:] in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
          +[InviteHelpers findPhoneNumbersForContact:] in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
          _CopyValuesFromLinkedContact in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
          +[InviteHelpers findContactTwitter:] in libMedioEvent.a(InviteHelpers.o)
```

I have already included the MedioEvent SDK and its precompiled source in the project, and also included it in Framework and Library search paths. What bothers me is that it is coming from inside libMedioEvent.o.

Do I have to include "InviteHelpers" sdk as well?

Comment: You are missing the AddressBook framework. Add it to your project and you should be fine.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Now I am left with only one error:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBWebDialogs", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libMedioEvent.a(InviteStartupViewController.o)

and updating Facebook SDK to see if it vanishes.

Comment: For reference, the integration documentation is [here](http://k-invite.com/support/documentation/ios-integration/). It includes the list of required frameworks.